# set state array with nested array values from object

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I initialize component state with the store state which pulls api data.
I filter the array of data by object name. This then will setState with the object chosen by the user via a button. This works, all objects change without issue. The problem I cannot for the life of me figure out is what I want is to setState onClick with a nested array of objects associated with the category. So each category object has a nested subCategory array which holds many subCategories.

So a generic example would be:

```
const arr = [
 { name: 'Do', id: 1, sub: [{sub_id: 1, something: 'dog'}, {sub_id: 1, something: 'cat'}] },
 { name: 'Re', id: 2, sub: [{sub_id: 2, something: 'bird'}, {sub_id: 2, something: 'mouse'}] },
 { name: 'Me', id: 3, sub: [{sub_id: 3, something: 'lion'}, {sub_id: 3, something: 'moose'}] }
];
class BrainFart extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
       super(props)
       this.state = { foo: [] }
    }
    handleArray() {
      const stuff = arr.filter(c => c.sub)
      this.setState({foo: stuff})
    }

}
```

This will not set state with the nested array of sub...
Any thoughts?
Thank you

Comment: To quote the `push()` doc: The push() method adds one or more elements to the end of an array and *returns the new length of the array*.

Comment: after your last edit, what's your desired output? you expect your three `arr` items in `state.foo`? or want the six (total items when combining all the `sub` arrays)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update your `handleArray` function to:

```
handleArray() {
    const stuff = arr.filter(c => c.sub);

    this.setState({ foo: [...this.state.foo, ...stuff] });
}
```

Note the change when setting new value for `foo` property on component state. In this case we create a new array based on the previous and new data (`stuff`).

Read more on react docs about [how to modify component state](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#do-not-modify-state-directly).

---

Current problem is setting `foo` to the output of `foo.push(stuff)`.

> The push() method adds one or more elements to the end of an array and returns the new length of the array.

Read more about [push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

Comment: I ended up taking your answer and because of Flow had to process slightly different.  const stuff = selected.filter(b => b)[0].sub  this.setState({foo: stuff}) works great. Thank you

Comment: Ok. Feel free to mark/accept the answer. Question based on your comment: Is it fine for you to keep only the first `sub` array, or the final intention is to get an array with all the items on all `sub` arrays?

Comment: I would like to do both actually but can only figure out how to get one sub array at a time on click. In a perfect situation I would like to display every single item from all of the sub arrays for each category then filter through them as user clicks on tag

Comment: You can achieve that using `array.reduce` to flatten all `sub` arrays.